# Generate extra column in a dataframe by concating all the columns whose headers matches with strings in a list using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named :- `df_explode`
[inputdataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfuMg.png)

I have a list of strings "`myList_groupby`".

```
myList_groupby =  ["domain","tag_name","tag_hierarchy","html_attributes","extension","xyz"]
```

I want to generate a new column named "combined" in `df_explode`,whose elements will be a string concatenation  for all the columns whose header matches with strings in `myList_groupby` list.(is in `myList_groupby`)

Output dataframe :-

[outputdataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfuMg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need filter columns by subset and call `join` per rows:

```
df['new'] = df[myList_groupby].apply('_'.join, axis=1)
```